# How to access variable values while using host vars in for loop in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How to access variable value while dealing with group vars.

Ansible 2.5

```
{% for ----%}
{% set floop = loop %}
{% for host in groups['web{{floop.index}}']%}
            --- block of code ---
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

inventory file:

```
[web1]
host1
host2

[web2]
host3
host4
```

It is giving me the below error.

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'web{{loop.index}}'
```

Could anyone please suggest how to use index value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that each host group is looped over separately, you could use the following code (or something similar to it). The `if` statement is there to ensure you are only looping over group that are named `web<number>`:

```
{% for group in groups %}
{% if group | regex_search('^web\d+') %}
{% for host in groups[group] %}
--- block of code ---
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

This was my original answer. Leaving it here in case it helps someone else.

Use a parent host group instead. Depending on your specific use case, this is probably a better and safer approach anyway.

Inventory:

```
[web1]
host1
host2

[web2]
host3
host4

[web:children]
web1
web2
```

Loop:

```
{% for host in groups['web'] %}
--- block of code ---
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi,
If I use the above code, In both the iterations it gives full host details.
My requirement is in the first iteration it should display only web1 host details and in second iteration it should display web2 host details.
That is why I'm trying to use loop.index values .

Comment: {% for host in groups['web']%}
            --- block of code ---
{% endfor %}
Without if statement also we are only looping over group that are named web<number>.
But my requirement is I need to loop over for web1 first then next web2.

Comment: The `if` statement is there to make sure you only loop over groups named `web1`, `web2`, etc. It ensures you do not repeat for default groups like `all` and `ungrouped`, and any other groups you have defined. If you know for sure that it is only `web1` and `web2`, then why not just hard code those names in your for loop?

Comment: I think you may be looking at the bottom (original) section of my answer. Make sure to only look at the top section for your purposes. It individually loops over `web1` and `web2` groups